# error NU1202: Cannot install global .net tool

Tags: c#, .net

How can I resolve these dependencies? I installed everything through visual studio.
It looks like everything should be installed correctly, I have .net 5 sdk. Which I'm assuming includes `.NetCoreApp`. Why the complaint about `.NetFramework`?

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
error NU1202: Package dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator 5.0.2 is not compatible with net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0) / any. Package dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator 5.0.2 supports: net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0) / any
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading a previous version. I looked at https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator/6.0.0-preview.1.21112.2

and picked version 3.1.3 and was able to download package.

You may need to downgrade other related packages as well.